# Unable to transform meshs in object mode

Tags: mesh

I  can’t transform the meshes of a blender file. I think it is related to the axis cursor next to the meshes.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Answer (score 2):

In tools options (popover in the viewport top right corner), disable "[Affect only origins](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/tools/tool_settings.html#bpy-types-toolsettings-use-transform-data-origin)".